# Enable event handler?

Tags: vba, event-handling

Fellow sufferers

I wish to use event handling when someone selects a cell. I made an eventhandler function which starts like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

The eventhandler does not get called when i change cell. Do I need to enable event handling or what am I doing wrong?

BW Peter Bunde Hansen

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, please mark the answer as complete if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

To add an event handler for selection change on Sheet 1, ensure you are in the module for the correct sheet and use the below code:

[image: Ensure the correct sheet is selected]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

To add an event handler for the entire workbook to get a selection change in any sheet, ensure you are in the ThisWorkbook module and use the below:

[image: Thisworkbook]

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```